# How to find arc length / curve length reparameterization of b-spline curve?

Tags: python, curve, spline, bspline

I'm trying to generate a quadratic b-spline curve from a set of controlpoints and a knot vector. How can I reparametrize the curve so that it is parameterized according to the arc / curve length? For example, if the curve is parameterized for t=0 to t=1, inputting t=0.2 should give the curve coordinate that occurs when the distance along the curve is 20% of it's total length.

Basically, how do I generate a second B-Spline that is parameterized according to its length? I am OK with a solution that is reasonably approximate.

This code example illustrates my issue - the resulting red asterisks on the plot are not equally spaced, even though the parametric values (u) were.

```
from splipy import Curve, BSplineBasis
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

ORDER = 3  # quadratic B-spline
cp = np.array([ [0,0,0], [0, 1,0], [0,2,0], [0,3,0], [1,3,0],[2,3,0], [3,3,0]])
num_cp=cp.shape[0]

# Create Curve
knot = np.array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 1. , 1. ])
basis = BSplineBasis(order=ORDER, knots=knot, periodic=-1)
curve = Curve(basis=basis, controlpoints=cp, rational=False)

# Sample along curve
t = np.linspace(0,1,100)
points_along_curve = curve(t)

# Sample 10 linear points to illustrate they are not equally spaced along curve
u = np.linspace(0,1,10)
points_10_uneven = curve(u)

# Plot results
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') 

# Plot curve
x,y,z = points_along_curve.T
ax.plot(x,y,z,'b-')

# Plot 10 linearly-sampled points (to illustrate they are not equally spaced along curve)
x,y,z = points_10_uneven.T
ax.plot(x,y,z,'r*')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the red asterisks near the ends of the curve are more spaced apart than the red asterisks at the bend in the curve.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, what you are asking for **cannot be done** in general. A spline curve is a piecewise polynomial parametric curve and [as noted for example here](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/PARA-chord-length.html):

*"..it is known (proved by R. Farouki and also well-known in geometry) **that polynomial curves cannot be parameterized to have unit speed** (i.e., arc-length parameterization), the chord length can only be an approximation"*

See also [this presentation](https://faculty.engineering.ucdavis.edu/farouki/wp-content/uploads/sites/41/2013/02/Introduction-to-PH-curves.pdf) for more references (slide 6 states the impossibility theorem).

There is, however, literature on approximating an arc-length parameterization using spline (or rational spline) curves and the links above are a good place to start.